# WPF Helper class with static DependencyProperty used on several open windowss

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview, dependency-properties

I have the following helper class in WPF:

```
    public class EnhancedTreeView : TreeView, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItem", typeof(Object), typeof(EnhancedTreeView), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public new Object SelectedItem
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedItemProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
            NotifyPropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    public EnhancedTreeView()
    {
        SelectedItemChanged += MyTreeView_SelectedItemChanged;
    }

    private void MyTreeView_SelectedItemChanged(Object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<Object> e)
    {
        SelectedItem = base.SelectedItem;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String aPropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(aPropertyName));
    }
}
```

It works all fine on a page:

```
 <local:EnhancedTreeView
                x:Name="StructureTreeView"
                Grid.Column="0"
                Margin="5"
                BorderThickness="0,0,1,0"
                BorderBrush="LightBlue"
                Background="#FFFAFAFA"                                            
                DataContext="{Binding Path=TreeViewModel}" 
                SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedTreeViewItem, Mode=TwoWay}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
```

But my problem is that if I open a new window using the same XAML as the one above, I have two instances of the TreeviewHelper but just one static DependencyProperty.

So when the user selects a node in the treeview in one wind or page, both treeviews reacts because they are bound to the same static DependencyProperty.

What is the easiest workaround/solution to this problem ?, and no, don't make the DependencyProperty non-static, as it will Throw Up when WPF detects two identical Dependencyproperties.

Comment: i think you misunderstood dependency properties, your code mixes viewmodel code (INotifyPropertyChanged) with View code (Dependency properties).

Comment: thumbmunkeys, You're right !!, I removed the INotifyPropertyChanged interface and the related code from the Helper class. But the original problem remains.

Comment: my guess is you are binding to the same instance of `TreeViewModel` in both views. The registering of DependencyProperties is supposed to be static

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I was refering to the same ObservableCollection in both treeviews, when I changed the two viewmodels to populate their own ObservableCollection and each use their won SelectedTreeViewItem, the problem with the Dependencyproperty was gone.

Thanks for all advice, that made me cleanup my code.